# Reduce processing power on query

Tags: mysql, database, performance, processing-efficiency

I'm dealing with a table that where new rows are added several times per minute. Just as often do I need to run the query below, which I believe is the cause for recent lag spikes.

Is there any way I can make this query more efficient?

```
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT SUM(amount) 
  FROM transactions 
  WHERE to_account=:account), 0) - IFNULL((SELECT SUM(amount) 
  FROM transactions WHERE from_account=:account), 0) as balance;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transactions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_account` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `to_account` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fee` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  `ip` varchar(39) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('CLAIM','REFERRAL','DEPOSIT','WITHDRAWAL') NOT NULL,
  `is_processed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `from_account` (`from_account`),
  KEY `to_account` (`to_account`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=24099 ;
```

Comment: Can you post the indexes you have defined on the transactions table?

Comment: Added the table structure. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your two table-reading queries are

```
SELECT SUM(amount) 
  FROM transactions
 WHERE from_account = constant
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(amount) 
  FROM transactions
 WHERE to_account = constant
```

The first of these can be optimized by a compound index on (from_account, amount) because it allows the query to be satisfied by an index range scan. The second query can be satisfied with a similar index. You can get rid of your indexes on from_account and to_account, replacing them with these compound indexes.

It is still possible that you have contention between your INSERT and SELECT queries. But indexing for the SELECTs should reduce that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the lag as you experience might not be 100% preventable, but there is a small index trick which can reduce the chance on this lag:

> Use a multi column index on all the values you use and or return in your query.

In your case that would be:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_nn_1 ON transactions(from_account,amount);
CREATE INDEX idx_nn_2 ON transactions(to_account,amount);
```

What this does is take care that the real records from the database do not have to be read to get you your result.

There is a drawback: Updating/inserting records in a multi column index is slower then in a single column index. The trade off here can only be determined by testing.

Answer (score 0):

Also, simplify the query:

```
SELECT 
    ( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(amount), 0) FROM transactions WHERE to_account = ... ) -
    ( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(amount), 0) FROM transactions WHERE from_account = ... )
                  AS balance;
```

The table does not seem vary big, but check your setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.